# Does Morita Equivalence preserve irreducible, indecomposable modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have a fairly simple question that I'm not sure of the answer to. If we have Morita equivalent rings $R$ and $R'$ (i.e. the categories $R$-Mod and $R'$-Mod are equivalent with equivalence $\mathcal{F}$), does $V$ being an irreducible $R$-module imply that $\mathcal{F}V$ is an irreducible $R'$ module? What if $V$ was indecomposable?

What I've tried: I know intuitively that Morita invariant properties tend to be properties defined only in terms of modules and homomorphisms, rather than of elements in the ring.  I also know that all simple modules are indecomposable, so answering the second question would be enough. I'm inclined to say that both of these properties are preserved, but can't convince myself fully. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Right! If you can pose/phrase the question in "naive categorical/mapping" terms, you're done. :)

Comment: You can use the fact that Morita equivalences preserve direct sums of modules (and of course isomorphisms).